# Android: Replacing HTML tags in WebView

Tags: android, tags, replace, webview

My android application downloads articles formatted with HTML tags and displays them in the WebView. The problem I have got is that some articles have auto generated graphs which are quite big and they don't fit the webview. (Please note that I don't want to use horizontal scrolling).
My idea is to save every occurrence of the 'div' tag that holds such a graph and then replace it with `"<a href='unique_id_of_div_tag'>Show graph</a>"` link. 
Having something like this will display link instead of the graph. When user click on it would open new activity with graph.(I would handle user clicks with WebViewClient and shouldOverrideUrlLoading method)

The 'div' tag which contains the grap info has similar structure to the following:

```
<div class="graph">
   <div>Header</div>
   <div>Graph body</div>
   <div>Graph footer</div>
</div>
```

(and I don't have a control over it)

To sum up, I want to be able to save content of the`<div class="graph">...</div>` and replace it with `<a href="">...</a>`. How can I achieve that?

Thanks,
marqs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using the following:

```
Pattern tags = Pattern.compile ("</?[^>]+>");
Matcher match = tags.matcher (yourContent); // here you specify the string you want to modify (HTML)
String result = match.replaceAll("");
```

This way you remove any tags, but keep the content in your HTML string.

Read more about Pattern and Matcher [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary.html).

EDIT:

To remove only links (anchors) from the string, write the following instead of the first line:

```
Pattern tags = Pattern.compile ("</?[a]{1}[^>]+>");
```

You can remove an arbitrary string by just replacing the regular expression with another one.

EDIT2:

I completely misunderstood your question. Two times :)

You can remove all `<div class="graph">` tags, by doing something like this:

```
    Pattern tags = Pattern.compile ("<div class=\"graph\">[^(</div>)]+</div>");
```

Afterwards, replace all those [[DIV]] placeholders with whatever you want. However, this approach will not work if you have a div with a graph AND some content inside it, though. So in that case, I think it will be best to split all your content on the `<div class=graph>` and then inspect every DIV inside every element to check if there is a graph inside it.

I don't know if this can be done with regular expressions alone, so a more tedious and bug-prone approach will have to be undertaken. But you do want something really specific, so that's something you should expect sometimes :)

Comment: Thanks but this will remove each <div class="graph"> tag which will break all graphs. From whole HTML body I just want to replace those div tags with <a> links - how can I do that?

Comment: @marqss, see my comment. I hope there isn't a weird bug in it (untested) :P

Comment: Thanks again! However I am not sure if that would work. Your patter will remove the anchors from the string. I have to remove divs (but firs save their values), I know that I can do so by updating your pattern however my div which holds graph data has also child divs and this wouldn't work. What do u think?

Comment: @Shade, much thanks! I came here looking to remove hyperlinks. However, your 2nd edit to remove hyperlinks only removes the start tags. To make it also remove the end tags, it needs to be: `</?[a]{1}[^>]*>`

Comment: @Shade also, if you want to prevent matching on other tags that start with 'a' (e.g. something like `<apple>Golden Delicious</apple>` in XML) then I think this should work: `</?([a](?=\s|>)){1}[^>]*>`

Answer (score 0):

Not being very familiar with Android or Java, but coming from a pure html/js point of view, could you do some pre-processing of the HTML before you display it in the WebView?  For example, if you know ahead of time what the graph html is going to look like, couldn't you just hide it in the html, and insert an anchor tag before it and show it with javascript?

I don't know the code to process or find/insert strings in Android, but the resulting HTML that you actually show the user could be like this, with the 'display:none;' added into the enclosing div of the graphic:

The link would find the element referenced in its href and then show it.

```
<a href="#div-of-graph" onclick="document.getElementById(this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf('#')+1)).style.display='block';return false;">show</a>
<div id="div-of-graph" style="display:none;"><img src="the-graph.gif" /></div>
```

Comment: The thing is that I dont want to dispaly that graph in the webview. I would like to be able to save the 'div' element in the String variable and then display it somewhere else (in another webview)...

Comment: Ah.  Are you the one generating the html content?